# Finding C# Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have following types of string file paths:

```
const string s1 = "~/somestring/somestring/somestring/somestring/somestring/someName_987x3474.png";
const string s2 = "~/somestring/somestring/somestring/someOtherName_222x666.png";
const string s3 = "~/somestring/somestring/somestring/somestring/someName_9871x3474_someString.png";
```

Now we already have a regular expression which can find the width of image for string s1 and s2 (987 and 222). It is this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?i)[^/]*?(?<width>\d+)x\d+\..*$");
```

This one works correctly for the first two strings, and I can get the width later on. But it fails for the third string. It is known that the paths will be of any length and will have file name in the following format:

someString_someNumberxsomeNumber.someextension
OR
someString_someNumberxsomeNumber_someString.someextension

Currently my regular expression only works for the first scenario.

I am later on doing something like this:

```
var v = filePaths.Select(f => regex.Match(f)).Where(m => (m.Success || !m.Success))
                    .Select(m => new MyClass
                    {
                        FileUrl = m.Value,
                        Width = int.Parse(m.Groups["width"].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    })
                    .OrderBy(t => t.Width);
```

The MyClass contains just two properties FileUrl and Width. Here FileUrl or m.Value should be the name of the file i.e. the entire string after the last / in the original path and width should A in AxB. For example - 987, 222 or 9871.

Thanks.

Comment: Your regex is matching "#x#." exactly, meaning that will only match on lines where you see one or more digits, followed by an x, followed by one or more digits, followed by a period.  I suspect you want to try to look at only the parts that contain the 987x3474 to retrieve the dimensions but your goal isn't exactly clear to me.

Comment: Make the dot optional. http://regex101.com/r/xH3iL5/3  or put .* before the dot http://regex101.com/r/xH3iL5/4

Comment: @Avinash - It crashes when I try to get the list of MyClass objects saying - Input String was not in correct format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you could just use `Path.GetFileName` and use a simpler regular expression on that result:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<width>\d+)x\d+");

var v = filePaths
             .Select(f => regex.Match(Path.GetFileName(f)))
             .Where(m => (m.Success || !m.Success))
             .Select(m => new MyClass
             {
                 FileUrl = m.Value,
                 Width = int.Parse(m.Groups["width"].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
             })
             .OrderBy(t => t.Width);
```

Comment: Sorry one mistake by me. m.Value should be the name of the file (the whole string after the last / in the original path). I have modified this just now in my question as well at the end.

Comment: @VVV: If I understood correctly, you should be able to use `GetFileName` instead. Let me know if that works.